# How to create a Mix Task to generate files

Tags: elixir

How would I create a custom mix task to dynamically generate code and files similar to how Phoenix does. For example Phoenix has generators like `mix phx.gen.html` that will dynamically add a bunch of files under lib. I'm not trying to accomplish anything that complicated just trying to figure out how to dynamically generate code. For example how would I create a mix task to generate file called `user.ex` with this code.

```elixir
defmodule User do

 def function1(arg), do: arg
 def function2(arg), do: arg

end
```

Comment: Start with reading the [Task docs](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html) and [this article](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/mix-tasks/), the first two hits when googling `mix task`. Pro tip: get fast access to help topics when you are in your `iex -S mix` shell by typing `h Mix.Task`, or `h File.<tab>` and see what you get.

Comment: @zwippie I read that article it's very basic. I know how to create a simple mix task that prints hello world to the console. I've googled a lot and have yet to find any info on how to create mix tasks to generate files. Stackoverflow is usually my last resort.

Comment: You could look at what [phx.gen.html](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/d25d4acaea299569b9035f36e946ed45fec758fd/lib/mix/tasks/phx.gen.html.ex#L104) does if you want an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo = your_app_name`

foo/lib/foo/mix/tasks/create_file.ex:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.CreateFile do
  use Mix.Task

  def run([file_name]) do
    app_dir = File.cwd!
    app_name = Path.basename(app_dir)
    new_file_path = Path.join(
        [app_dir, "lib", app_name, "#{file_name}.ex"]
    )

    File.write(
      new_file_path, 
      """
      defmodule #{String.capitalize(app_name)}.#{String.capitalize(file_name)} do
        def hello do
        end

        def goodbye do
        end
      end
      """, 
      [:write]
    )
  end

end
```

If you run the mix task:

```
~/phoenix_apps/foo$ mix create_file skeleton
```

`["skeleton"]` will be passed as an arg to `run()`, and the task will create the file:

```
foo/lib/foo/skeleton.ex
```

with the contents:

```
defmodule Foo.Skeleton do
  def hello do
  end

  def goodbye do
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking you had to do some complicated metaprogramming. Didn't realize it was that easy. This a great start.